# Python print len() of list being value of dictionary using list comprehension for loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary, inline

I have so far done something like that:

```
   count={'letters':['a','b','c'],'digits':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]}

    print ([k for k,v in count.items()],[len(v) for k,v in count.items()])
```

what prints

```
(['digits', 'letters'], [10, 3])
```

but I would like thanks to **list comprehension** print something like belowe and with use of **only one for** inline:

```
'digits', 10 ; 'letters', 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with one `for` loop like this

```
print [(k, len(v)) for k, v in count.items()]
```

**Output**

```
[('digits', 10), ('letters', 3)]
```

Comment: OK. It prints what I want, but will it be possible to manage somehow with one for ?

Comment: @andi Please check my answer now, it gives you a simple way :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something a bit more readable?

```
for k, v in count.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, len(v)))

letters: 3
digits: 10
```

Comment: I think it is not inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
> print {k:len(v) for k,v in count.items()}
{'digits': 10, 'letters': 3}
```

Also, `[k for k,v in count.items()]` is just `count.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> count={'letters':['a','b','c'],'digits':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]}
>>> print (' ; '.join(item + ', ' + str(len(count[item])) for item in count))
```

**Output:**

```
letters, 3 ; digits, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
print [(k, len(v)) for k, v in count.items()]
```

which yields `[('digits', 10), ('letters', 3)]`

Comment: `print [(k, len(v) for k, v in count.items()]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Missed one parenthesis. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible only with one for loop andi :)

here is how...

code :

```
count={'letters':['a','b','c'],'digits':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]}

for (k,v) in count.items():
    print k +',' + str(len(v)) +';',
```

output:

```
digits,10; letters,3;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With no for loops

```
print("\n".join(map("{}: {}".format, count, map(len, count.values()))))
```

or if you are happy with `['digits: 10', 'letters: 3']`, just

```
list(map("{}: {}".format, count, map(len, count.values())))
```

Comment: anyway I think, I will stay for "list comprehension" usage. You're number of braces used remembers me about Java ;)